# Encode html elements to JSON in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Im trying to encode the following string in php so that it can be sent as a JSON object:

```
success:{'id':'success=-message', 'class':'success-message', 'inner-html':'Congratulations! You have been succesfully logged in'},

logout: {'type'='button', 'value'='logout', 'class'='logout-button'},

sessionID: {'type'='hidden', 'name'='sessionID', 'value'=1}
```

How can i format it so that it can be encoded properly using json_encode()?

Comment: json_encode will take in strings no problem. But it looks more like you've got a pseudo-js Object definition, and want to convert it to an equivalent PHP structure so you can convert it back to json?

Comment: yes i want a JSON object with success, logout and sessionID as indices where each is an array where i can access the individual items inside of them

Comment: so that's JS code you've already got somewhere? You're not going to be able to use PHP to convert that to json without implementing a javascript parser in PHP. if it's already in JS to being with, then you've got `JSON.stringify()` to do the conversion for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{'success':{'id':'success=-message', 'class':'success-message', 'inner-html':'Congratulations! You have been succesfully logged in'},

'logout': {'type'='button', 'value'='logout', 'class'='logout-button'},

'sessionID': {'type'='hidden', 'name'='sessionID', 'value'=1}}
```

You just need the curly brackets (begin & end) to make this a valid JSON array.

And the keys need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

you say it's a string? Then it looks almost exactly json encoded already. Just encase it in square brackets:

```
echo "var myAssociativeArray = [ 
    success:{'id':'success=-message', 'class':'success-message', 'inner-html':'Congratulations! You have been succesfully logged in'},
    logout: {'type'='button', 'value'='logout', 'class'='logout-button'},
    sessionID: {'type'='hidden', 'name'='sessionID', 'value'=1}
];";
```

BUT, it seems like you're creating this string on the PHP side (correct?) which means you're doing `json_encode`'s work for it. Instead, you should have something like:

```
//This is a temp array just to show you how it works:
$myArr = array(
    "success" => ( object ) array(
        "id" => "success=-message",
        "class" => "success-message",
        "inner-html" => "Congratulations! You have been succesfully logged in"
    )
);

//Now you output the json version
echo json_encode( $myArr );
```